# Group validation in codeigniter

Tags: validation, codeigniter

I am trying to find out if what i am attempting is feasible.

I have four input boxes on a page, these have to be filled with alphanumeric codes found on cereal boxes for example. Now there are two types of tokens, you can either enter two of the large tokens or four of the small tokens.

What would be the best way to validate knowing that they could enter either 2, 3 or 4 codes depending on what tokens they use.

I tried looking at conditional validation but thought I would ask on here before wasting my time going down that path.

EDIT
Is it possible to do this using the form_validation library?

Comment: Yes. Pretty much anything is possible in PHP. We can only really comment on how well your solution fixes the problem.

Comment: Sorry but maybe my question was not clear enough. I know I can do this with PHP but I want to know if I can do this using the codeigniter form_validation library.

Answer (score 1):

You would be best to use callbacks for custom form validation in CodeIgniter. You could fire just on callback on one of the inputs and check the post data for all the inputs, or do a callback for each one.

More here:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks